# Implementing UIScrollViewDelegate methods in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using a custom UITableView that complies to those protocols:

- UITableViewDataSource
- UIScrollViewDelegate

This table view is used in many places in my app. I have implemented image downloading in the background. When the user scrolls, additional images get downloaded – that's why I needed to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate methods. I definitely want to have this in this class and not in a view controller, because each of these custom table views use the same implementation of the methods.

Here is the problem. In my view controller, I need to implement the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method from UITableViewDelegate, because I need to perform a segue. But when I do that (and set the delegate to self), the UIScrollViewDelegate methods get caught by this view controller and are not propagated to the table view, because UITableView extends UIScrollView (and his delegate methods).

I have "solved" it by adding this to each of my view controller:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    [self.bookTableView scrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView willDecelerate:decelerate];
}
```

But having this same block of code (FYI this is only one of them, there are some more) on many places throughout the app isn't very good. Do you have any ideas how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by using the new feature in iOS 6 – embedded view controllers. In each view controller, where I'm using this table view controller, I perform this:

```
self.tableViewController.tableView = self.bookTableView;
[self addChildViewController:self.tableViewController];
```

Where self.bookTableView is the UITableView in my view.

To perform a segue from this child TVC, you can use this:

```
[self.parentViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Book Details" sender:selectedBook];
```

Answer (score 0):

> I definitely want to have this in this class and not in a view controller, because each of these custom table views use the same implementation of the methods.

No, you do not. `UITableView` is a view. It should never talk to the network. That is the function of the model (or possibly a model controller). The function you're discussing has nothing to do with displaying information. It has to do with fetching information.

What you want is to the scroll view delegate methods into a custom `UITableViewController` and subclass your other table view controllers from that. The actual downloads, however, should be managed by your model. Your view controllers should observe the model and update as it changes.

Comment: Thanks. I realized I don't need a custom table view, because the whole class was in fact a controller. So I changed that. Also, the model that communicates with the network is a @property. But it does not solve my problem. The UIViewController is launched with some views, one of them is the UITableView with that custom UITableViewController.  The custom UITableViewController complies to the UIScrollViewDelegate, the main UIViewController to the UITableViewDelegate, so it can perform a segue. Using the scrollViewDid(...) methods is still caught by the UIViewController.

Comment: Why is there a UIViewController and a UITableViewController? Why doesn't the UITableViewController handle both the scroll view delegation and the table view delegation? You can move the common bits (the scroll view delegation) to an abstract superclass. But you generally should only have one view controller per screen.

Comment: I cannot use a TVC because there are other views, like buttons, UIActivityIndicator (when the data are loading and the table is hidden), error labels etc., and a TVC would make it much harder (or impossible) to do that. Now I could use a custom UIViewController superclass, which would implement the UITableViewController methods/protocols, and inherit from that. But then again, that would be bad too, as the TVC is not in a generalization-specialization relationship with the view controller.